# How to create a docker file which has a standard python library for use

Tags: docker, dockerfile

need your help i have a standard python library which is in `.tar.gz` file. i need to manually copy the file in git repo to use it all the time. 
i need to create a docker container which will have this file and install the libraries from that standard library. 
need your help on it. i looking for a Docker file

tried docker file as below

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ls -ltr
EXPOSE 8080
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --skip-lock
```

I have a `.tar.gz` file which i need to copy it to docker and install the packages in it and use it containers

Comment: That looks like a normal enough Dockerfile; what issues are you having with it?

Comment: What's exactly your problem ?

Comment: okay let me elaborate it. i have a standard python library file which is in .tar.gz format. i would like to copy that file and then create image out of it and use it for my app to access it